# select from where with nested select inside the where using knex and mysql

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, knex.js

I have a one to many relationship with two tables. I need to use knex to perform a query where I have a piece of data that is only in one table. The query will use this piece of data to find a foreign key on a similar row to get data from the foreign table. To do this with a standard mysql query, I use:

```sql
SELECT 
      sellers_ID,
      sellerName,
      sellerUsername,
      sellerAvatar,
      listingID,
      productTitle,
      productImage,
      averageRating,
      reviewerName,
      reviewerAvatar,
      reviewDate,
      reviewRating,
      reviewText
    FROM
      sellers,
      reviews
    WHERE
      reviews.sellers_ID = (SELECT sellerID FROM sellers WHERE listingID = ${id})
    AND 
      sellerID = (SELECT sellerID FROM sellers WHERE listingID = ${id})
```

listing ID belongs to sellers and does not exist on reviews. I can use the listing ID to find a sellerID on the same row, which has a foreign key in reviews. So then I can get what I need from reviews using this listing ID. I want to use knex to perform the same query, but don't know how to handle the nested promises.

Here is what I have:

```
const promise4all = Promise.all(
    [
    knex.select('sellerID').from('sellers').where({ listingID : id })
    ]
  )

  knex.select(
      'sellers_ID',
      'sellerName',
      'sellerUsername',
      'sellerAvatar',
      'listingID',
      'productTitle',
      'productImage',
      'averageRating',
      'reviewerName',
      'reviewerAvatar',
      'reviewDate',
      'reviewRating',
      'reviewText'
    ).from(
      'sellers',
      'reviews'
    )
    .where({
      'reviews.sellers_ID': knex.select('sellerID').from('sellers').where({ listingID : id }),
      'sellerID'          : knex.select('sellerID').from('sellers').where({ listingID : id })
    })
    .then( result => {
      console.log('knex query result: ', result);
    })
    .catch( error => {
      console.log('knex error: ', error)
    })
```

I've experimented with promisifying the nested select query within the where, but it's not working. I receive this error:

```
code: 'ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR',
  errno: 1054,
  sqlMessage: "Unknown column 'sellers_ID' in 'field list'",
  sqlState: '42S22',
```

Comment: Why do you use reviews.sellers_ID on where statement there could be same field name in both table, so it is true just  knex.select(
      'reviews.sellers_ID',
      'sellerName', try this

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying

Comment: It looks like "ambiguous field reference" hence could you try exact table and field use in knex.select

Comment: It looks like I cannot use more than 1 table in knex.from().
If I use knex.select( item1, item2).from( table1 ) this is okay.
If I use knex.select( item1, item3).from( table1, table2 ) this is an error